# Transparent images' backgrounds become black when uploaded

Tags: yii, fine-uploader

I am using the Yii framework along with Fine Uploader to upload images onto my website. However, images with a transparent background (png files) will lose their transparency when the file is created in my website's images folder. Is this fixable? Thanks

Comment: Are you using Fine Uploader's scaling feature?

Comment: I am using the scaling feature

Comment: So, only the scaled versions are no longer transparent, correct? The original images are still transparent, I would expect. This is important detail to include in your question.

Comment: Sorry about not clarifying that. All images, scaled or not, lose their transparency upon being uploaded.

Comment: Then there is something else outside of Fine Uploader causing your issue. Original images are completely unchanged by Fine Uploader.

Comment: You're right! It turns out images were being cropped by jcrop, which had a default image background color set to black. Thank you, and apologies on not mentioning jcrop

Comment: Please include all of your resolution information as an answer to your question.